# Convert CD (cluster of differentiation) into gene symbol

Tags: public-databases

I want to convert names according to the "cluster of differentiation" nomenclature into accepted gene symbols. For example, CD3 should map to "CD3a;CD3b;CD3c;CD247" and "CD45RO" should map to "PTPRC". If the surface antigen isn't coded for by a gene, it should map to "" or something similar.

I've seen [Obtain CD (cluster of differentiation) marker expression information](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/obtain-cd-cluster-of-differentiation-marker-expression-information), but the Abcam table used there does not give the gene symbol -- it gives a list of alternate names. I've seen table 1 of [this paper](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/195/10/4555), but it contains errors -- for example, TNFRSF11 should be TNFRSF11A. I could copy [this table](http://www.hcdm.org/index.php/molecule-information) by hand, or I could download [this one](https://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/genefamilies/set/471), though that's annoying because it doesn't have one row per CD.

Is there a canonical (or just a convenient and reliable) way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using option 4 and parsing the columns for "Synonym" and "Previous Symbol".

https://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/genefamilies/set/471